# Al usar un scanner en JAVA, me sale error, la variable sc no esta definida

Tags: java, scanner

En el siguiente código, me sale el error *variable sc no está definida*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Iva {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        precioIva();
    }

    public static void precioIva(){
        System.out.println(" ingese numero");
        int precio = sc.nextInt();
        int resultado = precio + (precio /100) * 19;
        System.out.println("El total + el iva es igual a " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola YoungBood, bienvenido, el problema es que declaras **sc** dentro del main, y por lo tanto, **sc** "vive" dentro del ámbito ( **{ este es un ámbito }** ) del mismo, para corregir el error, declara e instancia **sc** dentro de **precioiva**, espero haber sido claro.

Comment: te invito a hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

El inconveniente esta en el alcance de tu variable, tal como se puede ver tu variable al ser declarado dentro de una función, el alcance solo esta dentro de la misma.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Iva {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); // La variable sc, solo esta disponible dentro de esta función.
        precioIva();
    }

    public static void precioIva(){
        System.out.println(" ingese numero");
        int precio = sc.nextInt(); // La variable sc, no ha sido declarada en este contexto
        int resultado = precio + (precio /100) * 19;
        System.out.println("El total + el iva es igual a " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Para solucionarlo podrías declarar el scanner a nivel de la clase Iva, o bien declarar nuevamente el scanner dentro de la función precioIva. Te dejo el código con ambas soluciones. Solo es necesario que implementes una de ellas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Iva {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in); // Solución 1, es necesario que sea static, para que sea ejecutado al mismo momento que la creación de tu clase main.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        precioIva();
    }

    public static void precioIva(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Solución 2
        System.out.println(" ingese numero");
        int precio = sc.nextInt();
        int resultado = precio + (precio /100) * 19;
        System.out.println("El total + el iva es igual a " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!